# A condition for $\emptyset \neq S\subset RE$ under which $L_S \notin RE$

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reference-request

I read some computation theory lecture notes and after citing and proving the proposition: $\emptyset \in S \Rightarrow L_S = \{\langle M \rangle : L(M)\in S\} \notin RE$ it says that $\emptyset\in S$ is not a sufficient condition, i.e $L_S \notin RE$ doesn't yield $\emptyset \in S$, by giving the counter example $L_{\Sigma ^*}:= \{\langle M\rangle : L(M) = \Sigma^*\}\notin RE$ . However it says that there is a necessary and sufficient condition under which $L_S\notin RE$. I searched in Sipser's book for this condition but couldn't find it. I would really appreciate a reference for this condition.

---

Edit : given the answer by @dkaeae , I wish to know what is the stronger property one can deduce about a non-trivial $S\subset RE$ in case $L_S \notin RE$.

Comment: It seems that you mean $\emptyset\in S$ is not a *necessary* condition from your contexts.

Comment: Added the definition of $L_{\Sigma^*}$. I thought I had a counter example for cases in which $\emptyset \notin S$ and $L_S \in RE$ and thus $\emptyset \in S$ is a necessary condition, but it seems I have a problem with this counter examples so I have to rethink.

Comment: The condition $\emptyset\in S$ cannot derive $L_S\notin \mathrm{RE}$. For example, if $S$ is the set of all languages, to which $\emptyset$ belongs certainly, then $L_S$ is the set of descriptions of all TMs, which certainly belongs to RE.

Comment: I deleted my answer because evidently I completely messed up decidable and RE... (It happens.)